# Is there a way to add an image into slide thumbnail only in PowerPoint

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

I want to add an image to the slide thumbnail in left panel, but it should not show in the Slide.

I found the following code to add image to slide:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape viShape = slide.Shapes.AddPicture(
            lockImgFile,
            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse ,
            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
            ICON_X, ICON_Y,
            ICON_W, ICON_H);          

            viShape.ZOrder(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoZOrderCmd.msoBringToFront);
```

but that's not I wanted because the image would show in the slide in the editing pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot - the thumbnails on the left are just smaller versions of the big slide. Anything you put on the big slide will show on the thumbnail.